# Rewriting is not working but gives an internal error in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://example.lk/example1/ln1/([^/]*)$ http://example.lk/example1?ln1=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.lk\/ln\/1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^contactus$ "http\:\/\/example\.lk\/example3\/cm\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.lk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.lk$
RewriteRule ^example2$ "http\:\/\/example\.lk\/example2\/a\/\$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.lk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.lk$
RewriteRule ^example4$ "http\:\/\/example\.lk\/example4\?\/vi\/\$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^example6$ "http\:\/\/example\.lk\/example6\/id\/\$1" [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^example1$ "http\:\/\/example\.lk\/example1\/ln2\/\$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please write what error you got, what you tried, what should happen and so on...

Comment: General tip: If you get a 500 server error, then your FIRST stop should ALWAYS be the server's error log, to see what really went wrong. Don't make us GUESS at the problem. Plus, the `"` around your rewriterules are unecessary.

Comment: I got an Internal Server Error . Nothings works here. As the anchor tags are linked to example.com/ln/1 but it shows an internal server error and all the other rewriting are the same as that

Comment: There are several problems in this code but actual reason of 500 you need to find out by looking into your Apache error.log file.

Comment: Can you tell me the problems in this code

Comment: First you need to check Apache error.log and tell us the reason of 50 error. I will post my comment/answer once I know the root cause of 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, there a number of errors, [please read the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

**You don't need to double quote or escape the redirect substitutions.**

**You don't need to match the `${HTTP_HOST}` if you don't care what it is.**

**You can't have a `$1` in the substitution without a matching group in the pattern.**

I've tried to fix some of the problems... but you need to provide more information on what specifically doesn't work and what you're trying to achieve.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example1/ln1/([^/]*)$ http://example.lk/example1?ln1=$1 [L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.lk/ln/1 [R=301,L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^contactus$ http://example.lk/example3/cm/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.lk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.lk$
RewriteRule ^example2$ http://example.lk/example2/a/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.lk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.lk$
RewriteRule ^example4$ http://example.lk/example4/vi/ [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^example6$ http://example.lk/example6/id/ [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^example1$ http://example.lk/example1/ln2/ [R=301,L]
```